# perl regex works unstable

Tags: regex, perl, cookies

I have session validation script that extracts session ID from cookie using following regex:

```perl
my $req = Apache2::Request->new(my $r);
my $cookie = $req->headers_in->{Cookie} || undef;
if ($cookie) {
    $cookie =~ s/SESSION_ID=(\w+)/$1/;
    ...
}
```

Cookie has format like: SESSION_ID=eac9a769e76a26a619c176b18b5b3db0

however from time-to-time I get following error in apache error log:

```
[Sat Jan 18 20:32:51 2014] [error] Invalid session ID: SESSION_ID=eac9a769e76a26a619c176b18b5b3db0 at /usr/share/perl5/Apache/Session/Generate/MD5.pm line 42.\n
```

This obviously means that this regex doesn't work sometimes:

```
$cookie =~ s/SESSION_ID=(\w+)/$1/;
```

the same issue occurs with some other regexs, I am running mod_perl2 with perl 5.10. Does anybody face similar issues? How to troubleshoot this?

Comment: What does the apache error have to do with the perl regexp code? Why is it obvious that it means that the regexp doesn't work?

Comment: Side note; `$cookie =~ s/SESSION_ID=//;`

Comment: @Barmar, it states that "SESSION_ID=eac9a769e76a26a619c176b18b5b3db0" passed to Apache::Session::File to validate session instead of "eac9a769e76a26a619c176b18b5b3db0"

Comment: @mpapec just tested `$cookie =~ s/SESSION_ID=//;`, the behavior is the same: 5 times the page reloaded correctly, on 6th - 500 error shown with the same error in log.  I dont understand why this happens, servers resources are OK, can it be related to some mod_perl apache settings?

Comment: It seems very unlikely that perl would get something like this wrong, it's basic to most scripts. It's more likely that something is changing `$cookie` later and adding back `SESSION_ID=`. Or maybe the `$cookie` has more than one cookie whose name ends with `SESSION_ID`. Try printing `$cookie` before and after the regexp.

Comment: that's funny guys, but looks like I found the root cause of this issue: it was caused by `undef` in this line:    `my $cookie = $req->headers_in->{Cookie} || undef;`,  I removed `|| undef`, and pressing 20 times the reload page button, doesn't show the error anymore.  Still strange behaviour of `undef` for me..

Comment: Well is thats causing the issue ..I suggest you use warnings and strict in your code , to just verify if your $cookie is getting set to undef . As using that if  $cookie is undef will cause your substitute to throw error

Comment: i always have strict and warnings in my scrips, however it didnt help to identify the problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is in {Cookie} shouldn't matter to the regex unless its undef.

```
 my $req = Apache2::Request->new(my $r);
 my $cookie_old = "";
 my $cookie = "";
 if ( exists $req->headers_in->{Cookie} )
 {
      $cookie = $req->headers_in->{Cookie};
      if ( defined $cookie )
      {
         $cookie_old = $cookie;
         $cookie =~ s/SESSION_ID=(\w+)/$1/;
         #   ...
      }
 }
 if ( $cookie ne $cookie_old )
 {      
    # do something with cookie if changed
 }
```

Comment: thanks so far, as I stated before removing `|| undef;` from $cookie checking line = solved the issue :)  Looks like I should be careful with `undef`